# Weird C# Ping Exception

Tags: c#, sockets, ping

I'm experiencing a very annoying problem in my C# application. For some reason, this code is causing a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException with result:
"No such host is known." and 'connected' is always false.

```
bool connected;

try {
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = pinger.Send("http://www.google.com", 15000);
    connected = reply != null && reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
} catch {
}
```

The strange thing is that both pinging using the command prompt and http requests all result in success. Does anyone have any idea why this code is failing?

Comment: Because a ping is not an http request. Change it to `www.google.com`.

Comment: `The strange thing is that both pinging using the command prompt and http requests all result in success` 1) No `ping http://www.google.com` fails 2) there is no http-ping

Comment: Ah thanks a lot kind sir. Mind posting the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing because it's taking the `http://` as part of the host name, rather than the protocol.

[Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) does not use the HTTP protocol, it uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). Changing the code to the following will fix your issue

```
Ping pinger = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pinger.Send("www.google.com", 15000);
```